# If I create an Android app that sends texts, will the text show up in the default messaging app?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I would like to enable my users to send custom texts from within my app.  These messages would be sent using their carrier via SMS.  I've never done this before, but it looks like I should use the [SmsManager Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) provided in the Android API.

Is there a way to send the text without it displaying in their default text messaging app (i.e. Hangouts, Messenger etc.)?  If that's possible, what happens when someone replies to the message that my app sent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send SMS using the SmsManager, and You can try below code:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg){
 try {      
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);   

    } catch (Exception ex) {             
          ex.printStackTrace();
 } 
}
```

Also you need to give SEND_SMS permission in AndroidManifest.xml to send message

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

In case if your message text is more than 160 char.then you may change your code as below:

```
ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(msg); 
        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `SmsManager`class to send text message.
firstly you have to get a instance of this class

```
SmsManager manager= SmsManager.getDefault();
```

then pass phone number and text message to [sendTextmessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

```
manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,null,textMessage,null,null);
```

You need to provide  user permission also

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will show up.
After android KitKat version, it is not possible to avoid writing sms to sms provider.
After 4.4+ the default SMS app takes care of writing the sent messages to the sms provider. Also only the default messaging app have the permission to delete sms.